# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException as well as java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle

I am using oracle 10g and Java. I am trying to retrieve  rows from one database and trying to update/insert its data into other tables.
it is giving me an error in Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NullPointerException`  and 
`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist within my results`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < edu_info2.length; i++) {
    if (url.matches("(.*)" + edu_info2[i] + "(.*)")) {
        count[0]++;
    }
    // if(title.matches("(.*)"+edu_info2[i]+"(.*)")){
    // count[0]++;
    // }
    if (k.matches("(.*)" + edu_info2[i] + "(.*)")) {
        count[0]++;
    }
    if (des.matches("(.*)" + edu_info2[i] + "(.*)")) {
        count[0]++;
    }
}
```

here i'm getting null pointer exception in matching statement.

```
while(rs.next()) {
        url = (rs.getString("url")).toLowerCase();
        if(!rs.wasNull()) {
            t = rs.getNString("title");
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        k = rs.getString("keyword");
        des = rs.getString("des");
```

`System.out.println(t)` is displaying results along with exception

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Null Pointer Exception during MySQL database write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221542/null-pointer-exception-during-mysql-database-write)

Answer (score 0):

The possible reasons include:

```
You are talking to the wrong database server.
You are talking to the wrong database.
You've misspelled the table or view name.
Someone has changed the table name or view.
Someone has deleted the table name or view.
Due to some configuration issue, application bug or whatever, the server, database, table or whatever name that you are using is different to what you think it is.
```

In short ... the name is wrong.

Comment: but everything is correct bcz in System.out.println(t); it is printin data frm database

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, so I will have to reply...

This error (NullPointerException) is not a bad error because it tells you exactly where it hit the error and what is equal to null. I suggest going through your code to find what exactly you may be missing, and if you can't, use the console to print out every variable you have. Once you find an output which says `null`, you know you've found your victim and you can do what was said, by filtering through your code to find why this is equal to null.

Comment: if (k.matches("(.*)" + edu_info2[i] + "(.*)")) this gives null pointer exception